# How to change the Asymmetric Key Pair without changing the Symmetric Key and the encrypted content in CMS with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have a X.509 certificate and the related PrivateKey.
I'm trying to encrypt a PDF document with java BouncyCastle with CMSEnvelopedData.

I can encrypt it and it returns sucefully encrypted file. I can decrypt and everything.
But now I want to change the key pair, but not the symmetric key and consequently, the ciphered document.

Why am I doing this? Because there are some situations that an application could change some assymetric algorithm and it's not necessary to reencrypt all the documents, but just the symmetric keys.

I know I can obtain the encrypted content with:

```
CMSEnvelopedData encryptedData = new CMSEnvelopedData(new FileInputStream("FILE"));
ContentInfo dataInfo= encryptedData .toASN1Structure();
```

After that I don't know exactly what I have to do to get the encrypted symmetric key. After that, I want to decrypt it, encrypt with another key pair and then create another CMS with the same encrypted data, with the same symmetric key and the new key pair.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You may have more success on the Bouncy Castle development mailinglists where the maintainers answer BC specific questions. Mods, this seems to be a valid question, sometimes with Crypto API's it's hard to know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Java crypto libraries actually have caught up to Bouncy Castle IMHO over the past few years. I had used BC on a few projects when Java crypto was lacking but since then implemented an entire security product just using the included classes.

Having said this (1st recommendation - use standard Java crypto - good examples, fair documentation), my 2nd suggestion would be to break-out the two components (my apologies but there is no Bouncy Castle specific info here as I haven't used those specific libraries in years):

1. Using a secret-key, symmetrically encrypt the plain-text and store the cipher-text BLOB separately.
2. Using asymmetric encryption (source private-key and target public-key), encrypt the secret-key and store that separately, referencing the key-pair, algorithm, etc that was used and a reference to the associated cipher-text BLOB/s.

To perform a key-pair or other asymmetric update (algorithm, etc), go through the records in #2 above, lookup (securely) the PKI private-key for the target and decrypt the secret-key. Then asymmetrically re-encrypt the secret-key using a new pair or other parameters (algorithm, etc). Overwrite the encrypted secret-key in record #2.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question. OP has already said he/she doesn't want to re-encrypt the documents.

Comment: There are two things going on, which may not be possible to separate within the library: 1. Symmetric encryption uses a secret. The plain-text is encrypted with this key. 2. Asymmetric encryption then encrypts that secret using a given PKI key-pair. Having the target PKI private-key can allow decryption of the secret and then (symmetrically) the source document. However, the library has to support this to know where the byte-block is that contains the secret inside the BLOB. The secret would have to be re-encrypted using a new key-pair but yes, conceptually the cipher-text could remain.